# Dev environment - Drives are at risk of running out of free space.

Tags: 2010, development, windows-7

> Available drive space is less than five times the value of physical memory. This is dangerous because it does not provide enough room for a full memory dump with continued operation. It also could cause problems with the Virtual Memory swap file: Macintosh HD (JAMES-PC - E:).

Is this warning anything to be worried about on a local dev enviroment (win7 native) ? i have 16gb of ram and 120gb of hdd space left(my maths puts 5x16 at 80, but hey). Im thinking it should not cause any issues as its not being used for production, but thought i better check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very common warning. You shouldn't have to worry about this Monitoring Rule in development. It is a default rule in SharePoint 2010 and is not always applicable or necessary at the 5x drive space level. You can ignore this rule in development (this is what I do). It should/will not affect your development work.

Technically, the best advice would be to go into CA->Monitoring and disable this rule. then create a new custom health rule, alerting levels of drive space to be 1x or something similar.  (Monitoring->health Analyzer->Review Problems or Review Rule definitions).

(Not advisable, but I know admins who even ignore this rule in production. Ekk.)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this rule using powershell. I have also disabled the rule for page file being larger than ram.

```
$spCentalAdminWebApp= Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration |? {$_.IsAdministrationWebApplication -eq $true} 
$spCentalAdminSite = ($spCentalAdminWebApp | Get-SPSite |? {$_.Url -notlike '*help'}).Rootweb
$spHealthRules=$spCentalAdmin.Lists["Health Analyzer Rule Definitions"].Items |? {$_["HealthRuleCheckEnabled"] -eq $false}
$spHealthRules  | select Title, ID | ft -AutoSize

Disable-SPHealthAnalysisRule -Identity "AppServerDrivesAreNearlyFull" -Confirm:$False

Disable-SPHealthAnalysisRule -Identity "PagingFileSizeShouldExceedRam" -Confirm:$False

$spCentalAdminWebApp= Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration |? {$_.IsAdministrationWebApplication -eq $true} 
$spCentalAdminSite = ($spCentalAdminWebApp | Get-SPSite |? {$_.Url -notlike '*help'}).Rootweb
$spHealthRules=$spCentalAdmin.Lists["Health Analyzer Rule Definitions"].Items |? {$_["HealthRuleCheckEnabled"] -eq $false}
$spHealthRules  | select Title, ID | ft -AutoSize
```

To get a complete list of the rules you can run:

```
Get-SPHealthAnalysisRule
```